# Getting value from array in a SELECT statement

Tags: sql, postgresql

Is it possible to define an array of text fields (or any data type) and select a value from it, all within a single statement? For example:

```
SELECT ARRAY['First', 'Second', 'Third'][mytable.state] as interpreted_state WHERE mytable.id = 1;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can sort-of do that with a SQL "CASE" statement, no?

```
SELECT CASE mytable.state 
  WHEN 0 THEN 'First'
  WHEN 1 THEN 'Second'
  WHEN 2 THEN 'Third'
   END 
  FROM mytable
 WHERE mytable.id = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM mytable.id WHERE columns IN ("1","2","3");
```

if I understood correctly what you meant..

Comment: I have an integer field (state in the above example) which represents a state. I'd like to return a textual representation of the state rather than the integer value. However, the textual representation is different depending on the id.

Answer (score 0):

That is really a silly way to do it. Have a lookup table and use a join.

Answer (score 0):

You're close, you just need some parens.

```
SELECT (array['one','two','three'])[state]
FROM mytable
WHERE id = 1;
```

But as already stated, the CASE statement is the standard and portable method.